# Call a specific page variable in Jekyll

Tags: variables, jekyll

Is it possible to call a **specific** `page.variable` into a layout in Jekyll?

I know it is possible to use `{{ page.title }}` in a layout to call the **current** page title, but is it possible to call **another** page's title instead.

**e.g**.

```
{{ pageX.title }}
```

Would return the title from `pageX.html`

I have searched and couldn't see a solution, I just wanted to see if anyone knows if this is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use page index in `site.pages`. Eg : `{{ site.pages[0].title }}`

Comment: Thanks! this works - could you help to elaborate on the '[0]'? How does that number get assigned to the page and is that something that can be changed?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how do you want to select the particular page. For example, I have a page category called "units" (accessible under "site.categories.units"). For every "unit" page I defined the YAML varibable "unit-id" in a unique (and human readable) way.

Imagine that I want to access the unit with the "unit-id" "my-first-unit". I can access the content of this page using:

```
{{ site.categories.units | where: "unit-id","my-first-unit" }}
```

If instead I want to do more complex things and I need to access any of the information stored in the YAML preamble (let's call it "whatever-YAML-variable") of this particular page, it's a bit more involved:

```
{% assign this-unit = "my-first-unit" %}
{% for unit in site.categories.units %}{% if unit.unit-id == this-unit %}{{ unit.whatever-YAML-variable }}{% break %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Notice that the instructions inside de loop are contracted (without linebreaks) to avoid the appearance of numerous empty lines in the output HTML. Furthermore, I added a "break" instruction to cut the waste of processor resources.

Also notice that you can easily add a few lines to control if the "my-first-unit" page exists, or even solve conflict in case of duplicates.

I admit that this is a rather clumsy way to do it, but it's a first solution. I will be looking forward to any other more robust suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your filenames are unique you could avoid a loop by filtering all pages for slug:

```
{% assign mypage = site.documents | where: "slug", "my-page-slug" | first %}
  {{mypage.title}}
```

If you have a page called "pageX.md" your slug would be "pageX".